# Laravel CSRF Token Mismatch Post request from seperate React project

Tags: laravel, csrf

I have a React project and a seperate Laravel project, which communicate with eachother. But whenever I send a POST-request from React to Laravel, it gives me a `CSRF Token Mismatch`. Now if the form was inside my Laravel project, I could just add the token as a field in my form, but it's a seperate project so I'm not sure.

I tried to add the token in `resources/js/bootstrap.js`, because I'm using Axios. I changed the code to:

```
import axios from 'axios';

window.axios = axios;
window.Laravel = {csrfToken: '{{ csrf_token() }}'};

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = window.Laravel.csrfToken;
```

But it still doesn't work, how can I handle this?

Answer (score 2):

First of all `csrf` work with `web.php` by default. So when you write a post request route within the `web.php` route file then you'll face `csrf` token problem.

##### Solution 1:

Whenever you're writing `Rest APIs` for `SPA's` or `mobile apps`. You should use `api.php` route file. Because in the `api.php` route file, some layers are excluded due to their stateless behavior.

> If you use `api.php` route file then you don't need to send `csrf` token in request headers.

##### Solution 2:

if you're writing `API` in `web.php` then you need to add that route in `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken` middleware `except` array, like following:

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'stripe/*',
    ];
}
```

In this way, that route will not throw `csrf` related errors.

*I hope that will helps you.*