# Laravel Sanctum SPA authentication 401 error with reactjs and laravel api and API authentication

Tags: laravel, authentication

I am trying to use Laravel Sanctum both for API authentication and SPA authentication. In SPA authentication. Do I need to define `sanctum/csrf-cookie` in api.php? If so, which one would be the correct one? 1 or 2? I got `204 error` if I use 1. I got `401 error` if I use 2.

1. `Route::get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie', [CsrfCookieController::class, 'show']);`
2. `Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie', function (Request $request) { return response()->json(['message' => 'CSRF cookie set']); });`

I have uncommented the following line as well.
`\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,`

bootstrap.js file

```
import axios from 'axios';
window.axios = axios;
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

.env file

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=http://localhost:3000
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
```

The registration function from UserController

```
public function registration(Request $request) {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);
        
        // Check if the email is already taken
        $existinguser = User::where('email', $credentials['email'])->first();
        if($existinguser) {
            return response()->json(['error'=>'Email already in use'], 400);
        }
        
        $user = new User;
        $user->name = $credentials['name'];
        $user->email = $credentials['email'];
        $user->password = bcrypt($credentials['password']);
        $user->save();
        return response()->json(['message'=>'User created successfully']);
}
```

signin function in UserController

```
public function signin(Request $request) {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);
    
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $user = User::where('email', $credentials['email'])->first();
            if ($user && Hash::check($credentials['password'], $user->password)) {
                $token = $user->createToken('api-token')->plainTextToken;
                return response()->json(['user' => $user, 'token' => $token]);
            }
        }
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Email or password is incorrect'], 401);
}
```

signout function

```
public function signout(Request $request) {

        $request->user()->tokens()->delete();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Logged Out'], 200);
}
```

To use the token I receive from signin function as Authorization Bearer, do I store in localStorage? I read somewhere that it is not safe and not a good practice to store the token the token in localStorage.

The following is signin.js file

```
if(email && password) {
      let item={email, password}
      try {
          await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/sanctum/csrf-cookie')
          const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/signin', item, {
            withCredentials: true,
          })
        
        if(response.status === 200) {
          console.log(response)
          localStorage.setItem('user_info', response.data.user.name)
          localStorage.setItem('api_token', response.data.token)
          router.push('/')
        } else {
          setsigninError('Error registering', error)
          console.log('error A')
        }
      } catch(error) {
          setsigninError(error.response.data.error);
          console.log(error.response.data.error)
      }
}
```

Is my API authentication using Laravel Sanctum correct?

Lets say I save the token I got from the signin function in the localStorage, I need to use that token in signin request as Authorization Bearer? How can I do that if I get the token after signin request. I really don't understand this.

This is the route I am redirecting after signin.

```
Route::get('/', [ProductController::class, 'showproduct']);
```

Please help.

Comment: First of all can you plz tell us, are you receiving `sanctum token` in your `SignIn` API response? One thing I want to tell you sanctum by default provide API access from of request origin. `FRONTEND_URL` should need to set your `Local React server URL` otherwise Laravel will not allow you to access API

Comment: Yes. I received sanctum token in my Signin API response.
.env file is as follow
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=http://localhost:3000
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost 
APP_URL=http://localhost:3000

Answer (score 0):

First you have to decide whether you want to use sanctum with stateless restful API or using session.

My solution is for Restful APIs.

- ##### Step # 01 (if you want to use sanctum token for Restful API)

go to `app/Http/Kernel.php` commit or remove `\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class` from `api` middleware group, like showing below snippet.

```
        'api' => [
        //  \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

> It is use for session base authentication but now we are using token base authentication so we don't need it anymore.

- ###### Step# 02 (Fix csrf token problem)

There are two ways to fix it one is, move your all APIs routes (those require csrf) from `web.php` to `api.php`.

The other way is to add that route in `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken`  middleware `except` array, like following:

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'stripe/*',
    ];
}
```

For more detail you can visit following [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73826232/12719616).

- ###### Step# 03 (append sanctum token with axios request):

In this step you will need store token in `Cookie` or `Localstorage` (depends upon you but I'm using cookie) and append `sanctum token` into axios request header. For this purpose you can register `axios reducer` in `bootstrap.js` which will automatically fetch token on every request and appends it into header. Intercepter prototype code is given below:

```
 axios.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
    config.baseURL = process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL   //backend server URL
    config.headers['accept'] = 'application/json';

    let token = Cookies.get("sanctum_cookie_name")
    if (token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }

    return config;
  });
}
```

- ##### Step# 04 (Attach sanctum middleware to route)

Following code reflect the example of route for `sanctum authentication`.

```
Route::get('/leaderboard', [LeadController::class, 'leaderboard'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and explanation. I stored the token in the localstorage since storing in the cookies is complicated for me. What about sanctum spa authentication? Can you please help me with that?

Comment: @saddysad update example is also work for SPA as well. Please explain be where you got stuck one thing remember you will need to attached `sanctum auth middleware` on route to enable sanctum authentication on route. i.e. `Route::get('/leaderboard', [LeadController::class, 'leaderboard'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');`

Comment: @saddysad if following question resolved your problem, don't forgot to mark as accepted as well as upvote the answer. This will encourage us to help developers.